# Lightswitch 2013 desktop client says it installed, but nothing there on start menu

Tags: lightswitch-2013

I'm trying to publish updates to my lightswitch 2013 project to an azure website.

After publishing, I can go to http://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/client/ and I get the message that the "App has installed successfully. Please launch this application from the start menu."

However, there's nothing added to the start menu. There are no new files added in documents/Microsoft/lightswitch

I've deleted and recreated the azure website to make sure there weren't any old files and still the same issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the message "App has installed successfully...", right click on the background and choose "Remove this application."

When that is done, I immediately got a "Install the app" button and everything updated correctly.